# Multiple States in React doesn't update which are dependent on other state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to update the State B when the value of State A fulfills the criteria but the state B isnt changing.

If the below code is run the value of B should increase by +1 whenever A reaches 100 , But when displayed the value of B remains fixed to 0

Here the pseudo code of what i am trying to do

import React , {useState} from "react";

```
export default function Test() {
const [A , setA] = useState(0);
const [B, setB] = useState(0);

 const handleStart = () => {
     setInterval( () => {
     setA(prev => prev + 1)
     if( A === 100){
        setB(prev => prev +1)
        A = 0
     }
   },10)
    
 }
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{A}</h1>
      <h1>{B}</h1>
      <button onClick = {() => {handleStart()}}> START </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setA()` method is an async method which is updating values asynchronously so your `if` condition before the setA may trigger first as React creates a batch of these async task. You need to move the logic into `SetA()` to make it working.

**Code -**

```
  const handleStart = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setA((prev) => {
        if (prev === 100) {
          setB((prevB) => prevB + 1);
          return 0;
        }
        return prev + 1;
      });
    }, 10);
  };
```

Working Example - [codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-67233827-r5j1t?file=/src/App.js:157-381)